# How to manage div positionning?

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to position 3 div. One on the left side that takes 25% of the window, one on the right side that also takes 25% of the wondow, and the last one on the center that takes the remaining space. I don't know how to do that.

Here is what I have so far :

**html:**

```
<div id="left">left</div>
<div id="center">center</div>
<div id="right">right</div>
```

**css:**

```
#left {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 25%;
}

#right {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 25%;
}

#center {
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    right: 25%;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Elfayer/VLjvK/

Comment: Check my answer at [3 divs side by side - the center one fixed width and other ones take the rest of the screen space][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327506/3-divs-side-by-side-the-center-one-fixed-width-and-other-ones-take-the-rest-of

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following is one of the ways to achieve this:

`float` all divs to `left` and assign `height` and `width`.

```
#center, #left, #right {
    float:left;
    height:100%;
}
#left, #right {
    width: 25%;
}
#center {
    width: 50%;
}
```

[**DEMO here.(with border)**](http://jsfiddle.net/VLjvK/4/)

[**DEMO here.(with background**)](http://jsfiddle.net/VLjvK/6/)

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, the borders are contributing/adding to the widths of the divs.

Add this to your CSS

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/VLjvK/2/)

Many would suggest NOT using absolute positioning as the primary layout method. This site might help you to more flexible solutions.

[**Learn Layout**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.. i have removed the absolute positioning.

```
        #left,#right, #center {
            height: 100%;
            float: left;
        }

        #left {
            background-color: red;
            width: 25%;
        }

        #right {
            background-color:green;
            width: 25%;
        }

        #center {
            background-color:yellow;
            width: 50%;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The left and right sidebars can now be of any width. The main width will be the rest of the space. All `div`s can have their own padding and margin as appropriate.

http://jsfiddle.net/Elfayer/VLjvK/

html:

```
<div id="right">right</div>
<div id="left">left</div>
<div id="center">center</div>
```

css:

```
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#left {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

#right {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
}
#center {
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VLjvK/5/)

I removed the `absolute` position and changed it to `relative`.

Also added `display:inline-block` and altered the percentage of the divs to accomodate the border widths

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    float:left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#left {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    width: 25%;
}

#right {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    width: 25%;
}
#center {
    border: 2px solid red;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VLjvK/8/

```
#left {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
}
#right {
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
    background-color: blue;
}
#center {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}
```