# How can I achieve this navigation bar layout?

Tags: html, css, layout

[image: navbar layout]

I am trying to achieve this layout using HTML and CSS, but I'm not getting anywhere. I tried something like this:

```
ul#nav-links-left
    Home
    Schedule
    Course & Venue

ul#nav-logo-center
    Image of logo

ul#nav-links-right
    Awards
    Results
    Contact
```

and floated them left, center, and right, respectively - didn't work. I also tried something like this:

```
ul
    Home
    Schedule
    Course & Venue

    Image of logo

    Awards
    Results
    Contact
```

but I couldn't get the logo to be in the exact center of the page.

The logo must be in the center of the page, the left and right sections of links must have the same width, and the links must be spread out evenly.

Any tips?

Comment: Can you add a working example of what have you tried?

Comment: look at this http://zurb.com/building-blocks/centered-top-bar-with-logo

Comment: https://codepen.io/davidcochran/pen/Fkwys is nice too

Comment: Maybe web dev is just not your thing. Could hiring a coder be apropriate?

Comment: Nope, I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
div#nav-parent{position:relative;} ul#nav-logo-center{position:absolute;top:0;left:50%;margin-left:-35px;}
```

"-35px" is half of width of image

Answer (score 0):

I am adapting the solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22327506/3-divs-side-by-side-the-center-one-fixed-width-and-other-ones-take-the-rest-of):

HTML:

```
<div id="nav-links-left">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Schedule</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Course & Venue</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="nav-links-right">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Awards</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Results</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="logo-center">
    <a href="#"><img src="logo.png"></a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#nav-links-left {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 ($logo-width / 2) 0 0;
    height: $logo-height;
}

#nav-links-right {
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 0 0 0 ($logo-width / 2);
    height: $logo-height;
}

#logo-center {
    width: $logo-width;
    height: $logo-height;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 (-$logo-width / 2);
    text-align: center;

    img {
        height: $logo-height;
        width: auto;
    }
}
```